# Pandas: agg take first value for multiple variables without the need to write it for each variable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm came across this challenge already multiple times and didn't find a simple solution yet.

Let's say, I have a pandas df with 25 variables and I want to sum over just one variable and keep from all other variables the first value I would need to write:

```
summedDF = df.groupby('V1').agg({'V2':'sum', 'V3':'first', 'V4':'first', 'V5':'first', ...'V25':'first' })
```

Is there a way to apply the function to take the first value to multiple columns without the need to write it down for each single variable?

Answer (score 4):

Craft a dictionary and pass it to `agg`, for example using [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

```
funcs = dict.fromkeys(list(df), 'first')
funcs['V2'] = 'sum'

summedDF = df.groupby('V1').agg(funcs)
```

Or with a dictionary comprehension:

```
funcs = {k: 'sum' if k == 'V2' else 'first' for k in df}

summedDF = df.groupby('V1').agg(funcs)
```